# React-native: Page navigation code returned error

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm building a react-native app using expo and I'm using the react native navigation library to navigate between pages and link my button to the next page but I've received an error. What do I need to change to get the pages up and to get the button (on the home page) linked to the second page?

Error: Unable to resolve "fbjs/lib/areEqual" from "node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\createHandler.js".
UPDATE: Now shoring this error too: Unable to resolve "./Components/DatePicker.js" from "screens\Home.js" bus is it possible that it's not related to the datePicker? I think it's about the react-native-gesture-handler. Do I need to do anything specifically for Android if I'm using expo to navigate to different screens?

AppNavigator.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Plan from './screens/Plan'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Plan: { screen: Plan},
});
export default AppNavigator;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "^3.0.0",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~6.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendar-select": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.5.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Is the error message "The development server returned response error code: 500"?

Comment: @Kabir Yes it is.

Comment: I think you should check this link : https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/721

Comment: @Kabir I've looked at the link however nothing on there has worked to solve this. Maybe the issue is more specific to my code.

Comment: @Kabir Thanks for your response. Should I remove it? How will my app use AppNavigator if I remove it?

Comment: Ok but i should postwhole code for app.js.....

Comment: @Kabir That's all my code for App.js because all my code that previously in App.js was moved to Home.js.

Comment: Ok check this link:https://aboutreact.com/react-native-navigation-router-version-3/

Comment: No need of <AppNavigator/> in Home.js file.

Comment: Please post here screenshot or logcat of error.

Comment: @Kabir Now I'm not receiving an error but the only feature that's rendered is the feature in the App.js file because my other features are in the home and plan file. Do I need a home.js page if my App.js is going to be my home page? Why would I need an app.js file and a home.js file?

Comment: “App.js” is the starting point of your Application that you are bootstrapping in “index.js.”App.js on the other hand has the root component of the react app because every view and component are handled with hierarchy in React, where <App /> is the top most component in hierarchy. This gives you feel that you maintain hierarchy in your code starting from App.js.
In app.js file,there is const of createStackNavigator.You can specify initialRouteName. It Sets the default screen.you should give   initialRouteName:’Home’.So you will get home.js as default screen in your app.

Comment: @Kabir I understand better why the App.js file is there now, thank you for explaining it.  I've updated my code although I'm still getting an error.

Comment: You have wrapped your `<AppNavigator />` in `<View>`. Remove `<View>` and just add `<AppNavigator />` in your app.js. @RJDdev

Comment: @KishanBharda Thanks for your comment. I've done that but I'm receiving a different error. I've updated my question with the error and my latest code.

Comment: Is `DatePicker.js'` is available in your component folder  @RJDdev?

Comment: Yes it is. Shall I add the code from DatePicker.js to my question? @KishanBharda

Comment: No you don't need to add code. Just confirm that you have exported `DatePicker` component in `DatePicker.js` ?

Comment: @KishanBharda Yes I have exported it.